# When logout from django admin: "AnonymousUser" object has no attribute "get_and_delete_messages"

Tags: django-admin, askbot

I created a *askbot* project by

```
askbot-setup
```

and

```
python manage.py syncdb # answered 'no' when asked to create superuser account
python manage.py migrate
```

I create a superuse from the *shell*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser('admin', admin@example.com', 'pass')
```

then I run the dev server and visit localhost from by browser

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Everything seems fine. But when I logout from the admin page, exception occurs:

```
AttributeError at /admin/logout/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_and_delete_messages'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/logout/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_and_delete_messages'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/user_messages/context_processors.py in user_messages, line 21
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
```

Tracebacks:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  140.                     response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_context
  159.         return RequestContext(self._request, context, current_app=self._current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  179.             self.update(processor(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/user_messages/context_processors.py" in user_messages
  21.     messages = request.user.get_and_delete_messages()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I also posted this at http://askbot.org/en/question/11782/admin-logout-throw-exception/, using *hailong* as user name.

I solved that problem by modifying `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/user_messages/context_processors.py`

```
# messages = request.user.get_and_delete_messages() .... original, prox. line 22
messages = get_and_delete_messages(request)
```

Because I find function `get_and_delete_messages` only defined as a "standalone" function in that file, and never a method of some class. But it is used as `request.user.get_and_delete_messages()`. I assume it's a typo. If I am right, another typo is in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/user_messages/__init__.py` (same usage).

Correct me if I am wrong. But it's likely my solution works.